# Google cloud speech to text grammar to narrow results to a number?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I very simply want to pass is a tiny audio clip (8Khz telephony) containing a single digit number, and get back a single digit number as text, narrowed down to a number.

File in > number as text out. Preferably via the python command line API.

The problem is, by default, it recognises things like 1,2,3,4,5 as  won,too,free,fore,5 ... no good!

I believe I want what is called a grammar? Or something like Amazon's number slot types it uses in Alexa? I've looked over the cloud speech docs and can't find it. The only thing I could think of is looping over the alternatives given and see if any match an int rather than a word. And if none do, then what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [speechContexts](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#FIELDS.speech_context). You can then add a few phrases that you think are most probable.

Answer (score 4):

A.Queue's answer is correct, however, in case others are bitten by the docs:

The [link given](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig#SpeechContext) suggests:

```
{ "phrases": [ string], }
```

The [python documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.RecognitionConfig.speech_contexts) says:

> speech_contexts
>
> Optional: A means to provide context to assist the speech recognition.

The python examples show:

```
language_code='en-US',
max_alternatives=max_alternatives,
profanity_filter=True,
speech_contexts=['Google', 'cloud'],
```

What actually works is:

```
speech_contexts=[speech.types.SpeechContext(
     phrases=['Google', 'cloud'],
 )]
```

I managed to get this from a Googler on Slack who pointed me to some alternative more comprehensive and accurate [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/#synchronous-recognition). Bookmark that last link for future sanity.